# javascript: prevent browser using shiftKey when using window.open

Tags: javascript

Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/casaschi/qKD9q/

```
<div style="color:blue;" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/search?q=' + Math.random(), '_blank');">
click me while pressing the shift key and then while NOT pressing it
</div>
<br/>
does one window appear as popup and the other one as a new tab?
```

If you click on the blue line on chrome or IE, a new tab will open.
If you shift-click on the blue line a popup window will open instead.

Is there a way to control from my javascript code how the new window is opened, for example always as a new window, regardless of the user pressing shiftKey or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That can't be overridden. Most browser features that allow the user's preferences in where to open a new window/tab can't be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').keypress(function(e) {
    console.log(e.shiftKey);
    if (e.which == 163) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    });
});
```

Try this. This will always open in new tab. Even with shift key pressed